# Rails Bootstrap Full Width Jumbotron

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I'm using bootstrap with rails and I've put the correct code in from the bootstrap documentation, but that doesn't work.  I've also put in code from other's projects and still my problem persists:  I can't get my jumbotron to be full width (of the browser).

Here's what I've tried.

1. Overriding the width of .jumbotron to width: 100% !important;
2. Adding a row div followed by a column div with col-lg-12.
3. Changing the div .container to .container-fluid

I'm stuck.  I'm wondering if it's a problem with the way I set up Bootstrap in my Rails app.  I'm going to paste the code below.  Any help is always appreciated.  Thanks in advance, internet.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">

          <h1>Welcome to Sewingly</h1>
          <p>A community marketplace for knitters, sewists, and other needle artists.</p>

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}


body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(http://i1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd370/kjames1581/jtronnew.jpg);
  height: 250px;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -9px;
  p { 
  color: white;
  }
}

js:

    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```

and the gemfile:

```
    gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '~> 3.3.0'
    gem 'sass-rails',           '>= 3.2'
```

EDIT:  Problem solved.  The answer lies in the HTML output that you can get through inspecting the element.  There was an extra container div bc I had wrapped all of my yielded content in the application html in a div labeled container as per Michael Hartl's tutorial.  I removed that div and problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.container-fluid` should work. Did you make other changes when you tried it? Here's a working example:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Welcome to Sewingly</h1>
    <p>A community marketplace for knitters, sewists, and other needle artists.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code exactly and it's still not working.  I'm thinking it is the way I configured my rails app and something I did is not working, my best guess is that the error is in the js application file but I'm not sure.  I posted above what I put in that file.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you render a page in your browser and copy/paste the HTML that is output? My guess is your layout has an extra `.container` wrapper in it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right.  I just pasted a ss from the HTML output.  I don't see that extra '.container' in my text editor.  How do I remove it?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you also need to see my _header.html.erb?  Could the extra container be coming from that file?  Thanks again.

Comment: So, it turns out that I had placed the yield of each page in my application html within a div that was causing the extra container.  It now works.  Thanks so much.